# How do I whitelist subdependencies on webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack, dependencies, bundle

I'm bundling code using Webpack with target:'node'.

I don't need to include all the dependencies and I am using webpack-node-externals to exclude node modules from the bundle. There are some modules I need to keep and I use node-external's whitelist option to do this.

However, my code is failing at runtime because the subdependencies of these whitelisted modules don't get bundled!

Does anyone know a way that I can bundle subdependencies too?

Thanks!